# MySQL query taking a long time on Join

Tags: php, mysql, join, indexing

I have the following mysql query which takes long time

```
SELECT `A`.*, max(B.timestamp) as timestamp2
FROM (`A`)
JOIN `B` ON `A`.`column1` = `B`.`column1`
WHERE `column2` =  'Player'
GROUP BY `column1`
ORDER BY `timestamp2` desc
```

I have index on TABLE A on column1 and indexes on table B are (column1,timestamp,column2),timestamp,column1.

When i use EXPLAIN it does not use timestamp index.

Comment: I've had trouble with MySQL's optimizer not using (preferring) timestamp indexes before. Have you tried [giving it hints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding an index...

```
  ... ON `B` (`column2`,`column1`,`timestamp`)
```

with the columns in that order.

Without any information about datatype, we're going to guess that `column2` is  character type (and we're going to assume that the column is in table `B`, given the information about the current indexes.)

Absent any information about cardinality, we're going to guess that the number of rows that satisfy the equality predicate on `column2` (in the WHERE clause) is a small subset of the total rows in `B`.

We expect that MySQL will use of a "range" scan operation, using an index that has `column2` as a leading column.

Given that the new index is a "covering" index for the query, we also expect the EXPLAIN output to show "Using index" in the Extra column.

We also expect that MySQL can use the index to satisfy the GROUP BY operation and the MAX aggregate, without requiring a filesort operation.

But we are still going to see a filesort operation, used to satisfy the ORDER BY.